# Page postback twice on the page having reportviewer

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer

My problem is, the *aspx* page is getting reloaded twice if the page having `ReportViewer` control. 
This is the code am having in my *.aspx* page,

My problem is, the *aspx* page is getting reloaded twice if the page having `ReportViewer` control. 
This is the code am having in my *.aspx* page,

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, 
    Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 
    Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %> <br><br>
```

and ..

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" 
    Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="7pt" Width="100%" Height="500px" 
    BackColor="#FAE28C" WaitControlDisplayAfter="10000" Visible="false" />
```

And this is in my code behind,

```
ReportDataSource rds = 
    new ReportDataSource
        ("dsSource", _PendingTicketAgeBC.SelectDailyTicketAgeInQueue(_SomeBE));
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath(".") + "\\Somereport.rdlc";

ReportParameter paramHedaer = new ReportParameter();
paramHedaer.Name = "paramHeader";
paramHedaer.Values.Add(mHeaderparam);
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { paramHedaer });

ReportViewer1.Visible = true;
```

Can anyone direct me the right way to resolve the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please provide us with more information. It is not normal for a Page to get reloaded twice without an action from you. Would you for example post your code ..

Comment: I have added my code which am using in my page. kindly help.

Comment: Nothing from what you have posted causes the page to post back .. How do you know it is posting back anyway?

Comment: My page is reloading twice. also I have placed a breakpoint in pageload. It is hitting twice.

Comment: What events are you handling in your page ?

Comment: only 3 events i.e Page_Init, Page_Load and my button btnLoadReport_Click. Am calling LoadReport() method in page_Load and button event.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24360/discussion-between-akram-shahda-and-gnanasekaran-kuppusamy)

Comment: Hey, chat is disabled/blocked in our company. :(

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue and was resolved by setting the AsyncRendering to false on the ReportViewer control. Note the the default value is true. Hope that helps